# Entity Framework closing connection after SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use repository and unit of work pattern in my app. I have an entity that I am saving:

```
public void Add(CustomerType entity)
{
   DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = dataContext.GetEntry(entity);

   if(dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached)
      dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Added;
   else
      dbSet.Add(entity);

}
```

Then datacontext `SaveChangesAsync()` is called to commit the changes. The entity is inserted in the db. The entity id is an identity column (database generated) and it is also set correctly.

After that, I try to load the entity again. The repository `Get(int id)` method doesn't use `dbSet.Find` but sends a new SQL statement to the db:

```
public virtual CustomerType Get(Expression<Func<CustomerType , bool>> filter)
{
    return dbSet.Where(filter).FirstOrDefault<CustomerType >();
}
```

However, I get the following exception: `The underlying provider failed on Open`.

Calling `Get()` normally (not after `SaveChanges()` works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: what are you doing in GetEntry method ?

Comment: @FrebinFrancis Edit the question to include the code.

Comment: Are you calling your `Get` method after the end (`await`) of the `SaveChangesAsync` ? If no, 2 connections may be used and an error using DTC or things like that may happens. BTW, if you call the `Get`method before the end of `SaveChangesAsync`, what would you expect to obtain ?

Comment: Yes I'm calling the Get() after await.

Comment: Having the same issue did you resolve this?

Comment: @Sanj No. I'm using GraphDiff now for updates as it will return the updated entity after it's saved.